# Tailwinds Intellisense not working when utilizing Next.js & vscode;

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, next.js, intellisense, tailwind-css

> Link to Github Issues:
> [click here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss-intellisense/issues/470)
>
>  At this link you can have the reproduction link;

Some info:

Using Tailwindcss-intellisense version: 0.7.6;

Using Tailwindcss version: 3.0.16

Package manager: NPM;

OS: Pop_os (Linux);

---

After the latest updates of Tailwind, I don't receive any of the suggestions when trying to add `className` to elements, I've tried to update the tailwinds files, changed the project, rolled back to previous projects and in any of these cases the autocompletion doesn't seem to work.

`ctrl + space` returns "No suggestions";

This is the output of the intellisense:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OHn3A.png)

Tried rollback some versions of the tailwind Intellisense, didn't work too.
The versions that I've tried:
(0.7.6, 0.7.5, 0.7.4, 0.7.3)

my settings.json:

```
{
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": false,
    "css.validate": false, // Disable css built-in lint
    "stylelint.enable": true, // Enable sytlelint
    "scss.validate": false, // Disable scss lint (optional if using scss)
    
    "tailwindCSS.includeLanguages": {
        "plaintext": "javascript"
    },
      
    "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
    "diffEditor.ignoreTrimWhitespace": true,
    "git.autofetch": true,
    "editor.fontSize": 14,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code, regular, monospace",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "[javascript]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.typescript-language-features"
    },
    "[handlebars]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "[json]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.json-language-features"
    },
    "[html]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "vscode.html-language-features"
    },
    "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "statusBar.background": "#7d58c2",
        "statusBar.noFolderBackground": "#492985",
        "statusBar.debuggingBackground": "#5900ff"
    },
    "liveServer.settings.donotVerifyTags": true,
    "editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true,
    "[javascriptreact]": {
        "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
    },
    "editor.cursorStyle": "line",
    "editor.cursorBlinking": "phase",
    "editor.cursorSmoothCaretAnimation": true,
    "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true,
    "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",
    "editor.smoothScrolling": true,
    "files.autoSave": "onFocusChange",
    "github.copilot.enable": {
        "*": true,
        "yaml": false,
        "plaintext": false,
        "markdown": true
    },
    "git.ignoreRebaseWarning": true,
    "workbench.iconTheme": "vscode-icons",
    "keyboard.layout": "br",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "strings": true
    },
    "workbench.colorTheme": "Horizon Contrast (rainglow)",
    "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
    "tailwindCSS.classAttributes": [
        "class",
        "className"
    ],
    "tailwindCSS.emmetCompletions": true,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the solution here:
https://plainenglish.io/blog/how-to-fix-tailwind-css-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code-3dede794df21

In a nut shell, you need to install the Tailwind IntelliSense VScode extensions and then add the lines below to your vscode Settings.json. Search for settings.json from your command pallete:

```html
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
   "strings": true
},
"css.validate": false,
"editor.inlineSuggest.enabled": true
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

The problem was my folder system;

That's the root of my project's folder:
snowsr/home/**[new]Workspaces**/Web/

The problem was solved by removing the [new] from the folder name.

Still doesn't know why, but this was conflicting with tailwind intellisense, and the intellisense really just not tell me about it.